# Webgl clear() issue

Tags: javascript, python, transcrypt

I ported a simple WebGL example to Transcrypt (see code below), to try it out, and it just worked! Apart from one detail; seems like the gl.clear() call is somehow not translated properly, as it gives the following error in Firefox:

```
TypeError: gl.py_clear is not a function
```

Commenting the line out makes the example work.

Python:

```
from org.transcrypt.stubs.browser import document, __new__


def make_shader(gl, vs, fs):

    prog = gl.createProgram()

    def add_shader(type_, source):
        s = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER
                            if (type_ == 'vertex')
                            else gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        gl.shaderSource(s, source)
        gl.compileShader(s)
        if not gl.getShaderParameter(s, gl.COMPILE_STATUS):
            return
        gl.attachShader(prog, s)

    add_shader('vertex', vs)
    add_shader('fragment', fs)
    gl.linkProgram(prog)
    if not gl.getProgramParameter(prog, gl.LINK_STATUS):
        raise RuntimeError("Could not link the shader program!")

    return prog


def attribute_set_floats(gl, prog, attr_name, rsize, arr):
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer())
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, __new__(Float32Array(arr)),
                  gl.STATIC_DRAW)
    attr = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, attr_name)
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attr)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(attr, rsize, gl.FLOAT, False, 0, 0)


def draw():
    gl = document.getElementById("webgl").getContext("webgl")
    gl.clearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0)  
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)  # <- error!

    prog = make_shader(gl,
                       ("attribute vec3 pos;"
                        "void main() {"
                        "    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 2.0);"
                        "}"),
                       ("void main() {"
                        "    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);"
                        "}"))

    gl.useProgram(prog)

    attribute_set_floats(gl, prog, "pos", 3, [
        -1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, -1, 0,
        1, 0, 0
    ])

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)


draw()
```

Html:

```
html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="webgl" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="__javascript__/webgl.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name 'clear' is an aliased name, since otherwise it would conflict with the Python dictionary 'clear' method, that receives special treatment by Transcrypt to allow arbitrary dictionary content.

(Transcrypt has no means of predicting the type of an object or variable since Python is dynamically typed.)

If you use 'js_clear' instead, it should work, so:

- `gl.js_clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`

Two alternatives, both NOT to be preferred in my view:

- Use `__pragma__ ('js', '{}', 'gl.js_clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)')`
- Use `__pragma__ ('noalias', 'clear')` to locally unalias 'clear'

All predefined aliases are listed in:

http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/special_facilities.html#pragma-alias

Also explained there is how to unalias a name.